# Error while installing wine

Tags: wine

While trying to install `wine` on my computer, I got the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.5.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wine1.5.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine1.5.1'
```

How can I install wine?

Comment: Please try `sudo apt-get install wine1.5`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using version 12.10